# .cmd runs from cmd.exe but not from start menu / Run dialog

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, file-association, run-dialog

**problem**

If I run a `.cmd` file from `cmd.exe` it works fine. However if I run it from `Start menu / Run` line, it opens in Notepad++, my editor. (*edit* I've it installed for years, didn't update it recently. However, this phenomenon with the `.cmd`s only started recently.)

Both time, I use a full absolute path. I use windows 7 x64.

**registry**

My `HKLM/Software/Classes/cmdfile/shell/open/command`'s `(Default)` is set to `"%1" %*` and `.cmd`'s `(Default)` is `cmdfile` in both `HKLM` and `HKCU` and there is no `cmdfile` in `HKCU`.

However the other keys I did not check / did not understand their meaning or significance, in particular I don't know an easy way to follow clsid values, and know what do they mean as a given key.

**context menu**

If I right click a `.cmd` the bold text <del>is its name</del> (*edit*) says "**Open**". But even from here if I click open, it opens in notepad++, my text editor.

**icon** (edited)
If I go to the folder in explorer, the icon is a Notepad++ icon.

**question**

Why is the Run line behaving differently from the command line?

How can I restore my `.cmd`s to run from the Run dialog, too?

Comment: Something is out-of-whack for sure.  If you right-click a .CMD then by default the highlighted action should be "Open", not the name of the .CMD.  Also Notepad++ doesn't appear to associate to .CMD file by default.

Comment: If you navigate to the path of the cmd file, in explorer do you see the batch icon or a notepad icon?

Comment: @AthomSfere it's a Notepad++ icon!

Comment: @techie007 sorry I realize the bold name was due me right-clicking it in Total commander. I did it in explorer and there it's 'open'. But the behavior is still wrong. Edited the q.

Comment: @techie007 I think definitely not N++: it does not associate like this (by default), I didn't do it willingly at least not from N++, and I use N++ for a long time and didn't do any updates recently.

Comment: Under `HKLM/Software/Classes/.cmd/PersistentHandler` there should be a GUID as the (Default).  For exmaple: {5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}.  Search the registry further for that GUID and it should (eventually) lead to you to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}` (again the GUID is an example, might not be the same on yours), which should have a default value of "Plain Text persistent handler".   Is that the case for you?  If this just started happening, have you tried a System Restore back to a point when it was working as expected?

Comment: @techie007 exact same values as for you everywhere. did not try restore yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a backup of the registry.

After that you should delete any values with "Notepad++" under the following key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.cmd`

The only keys I have under there are:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.cmd]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.cmd\OpenWithList]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.cmd\OpenWithProgids]
"cmdfile"=hex(0):
```

Comment: You were right! I had `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.cmd\UserChoice` (note **UserChoice**) key which contained `Progid="Applications\notepad++.exe"`! I've deleted these and it works. (Also had values in `OpenWithList`! They can go to.)

Comment: Thanks for posting your registry keys/values/data, gives comparison and confidence!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have somehow changed your default file association for .cmd files.

Navigate to any .cmd file:

- Right Click and select properties
- Where you see "Opens With" -> Click
- Navigate to %Systemroot%\System32\
- Choose cmd.exe

Your default association should now be fixed!

Comment: On Windows 7, when I right click or pick the properties of a .CMD file, I'm not offered "Open With".  You sure that works on your system?

Comment: I can confirm @techie007 , I see no "Open With" in cmd file's Properties dialog, neither as a button on any immediate tab, nor as a tab. Also not in the context menu, nor with shift+right clicking the file.

Comment: @techie007 Well, no it doesn't. I should have known better too! Generic advice is not always right, I should have double checked it too.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, if you aren't up to editing the registry, it's Start > Control Panel > Default Programs > Associate a filetype or protocol with a particular program.  (Often takes a long time to load!)  ".cmd" should be associated with "Windows Command Script".  Since it's obviously not, click Change Program, Browse to \windows\system32\cmd.exe and select it, checkmark the box for "always use", and that should fix the association.

Or you can do it directly in the registry, but the location will be under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, where file associations are set. CMD files are by default associated with the "plain text persistent handler". Default is:

### ======= for the .CMD extension ===========

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cmd]
@="cmdfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cmd\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
```

### ====== for CMDFILE type ==============

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile]
@="Windows Command Script"
"EditFlags"=hex:30,04,00,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,25,53,79,73,74,65,6d,52,6f,6f,74,25,5c,53,79,73,\
  74,65,6d,33,32,5c,61,63,70,70,61,67,65,2e,64,6c,6c,2c,2d,36,30,30,33,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,53,79,73,74,65,6d,52,6f,6f,74,25,5c,53,79,73,74,65,6d,33,32,5c,69,\
  6d,61,67,65,72,65,73,2e,64,6c,6c,2c,2d,36,38,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\edit]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):25,53,79,73,74,65,6d,52,6f,6f,74,25,5c,53,79,73,74,65,6d,33,32,5c,4e,\
  4f,54,45,50,41,44,2e,45,58,45,20,25,31,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\open]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):25,53,79,73,74,65,6d,52,6f,6f,74,25,5c,53,79,73,74,65,6d,33,32,5c,4e,\
  4f,54,45,50,41,44,2e,45,58,45,20,2f,70,20,25,31,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\runas\command]
@=hex(2):25,53,79,73,74,65,6d,52,6f,6f,74,25,5c,53,79,73,74,65,6d,33,32,5c,63,\
  6d,64,2e,65,78,65,20,2f,43,20,22,25,31,22,20,25,2a,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\runasuser]
@="@shell32.dll,-50944"
"Extended"=""
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{F211AA05-D4DF-4370-A2A0-9F19C09756A7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\runasuser\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ea72d00e-4960-42fa-ba92-7792a7944c1d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers]
@="Compatibility"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\ShellEx\DropHandler]
@="{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers\ShimLayer Property Page]
@="{513D916F-2A8E-4F51-AEAB-0CBC76FB1AF8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\ShellEx\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}]
@="{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the lovely editing example, naxa. Much clearer!